# Adapt file renaming script so that it searches out each file in sub-directories

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, rename

I have a `.csv` file in which looks something like this:

```
unnamed_0711-42_p1.mov,day1_0711-42_p1.mov
unnamed_0711-51_p2.mov,day1_0711-51_p2.mov
unnamed_0716-42_p1_2.mov,day1_0716-42_p1_2.mov
unnamed_0716-51_p2_2.mov,day1_0716-51_p2_2.mov
```

I have written this code to rename files from the name in field 1 (e.g. `unnamed_0711-42_p1.mov`), to the name in field 2 (e.g. `day1_0711-42_p1.mov`).

```
csv=/location/rename.csv

cat $csv | while IFS=, read -r -a arr; do mv "${arr[@]}"; done
```

However, this script only works when it and all the files that need to be renamed are in the same directory. This was okay previously, but now I need to find files in various subdirectories (without adding the full path to my `.csv` file).

How can I adapt my script so that is searches out the files in subdirectories then changes the name as before?

Comment: Could you rephrase the first line which is not clear?

Comment: edited, hope that's clearer.

Comment: Where is the location of `unnamed_0711-42_p1.mov`. Is is the same place where the script is run?

Comment: Just to clarify, the script i'm currently using (see my code) is in the same directory as the files- the script I require needs to search recursively i.e. its not in the same directory as the files (see last paragraph of my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to make this work, though it leads to an inefficient script, is this:

```
for D in `find . -type d`
do
    cat $csv | while IFS=, read -r -a arr; do mv "${arr[@]}"; done
done
```

This will run your command for every directory in the current directory, but this runs through the entire list of filenames for every subdirectory. An alternative would be to search for each file as you process it's name:

```
csv=files.csv
while IFS=, read -ra arr; do
    while IFS= read -r -d '' old_file; do
        old_dir=$(dirname "$old_file")
        mv "$old_file" "$old_dir/${arr[1]}"
    done < <(find . -name "${arr[0]}" -print0)
done<"$csv"
```

This uses `find` to locate each old filename, then uses `dirname` to get the directory of the old file (which we need so that `mv` does not place the renamed file into a different directory).

This will rename every instance of each file (i.e., if `unnamed_0711-42_p1.mov` appears in multiple subdirectories, each instance will be renamed to `day1_0711-42_p1.mov`). If you know each file name will only appear once, you can speed things up a bit by adding `-print -quit` to the end of the find command, before the pipe.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked, just to clarify, for "dirname" I should enter the top level/master folder beneath which all of the files are located (in sub-directories) correct?

Comment: ./rename.sh: line 7: /DG1440/tester_delete/anotherlevel: Is a directory
mv: cannot create regular file `/day63_testday2p1_0929-36_p1.mov': Permission denied

Comment: @bms9nmh No, "dirname" is a command. The only thing you should edit in the script I provided is the name of your csv file

Comment: OK, sorry, I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: Just out of interest and so I understand it better, what part of the script specifies that field 1 only (i.e. the old name) is input into the array. Thanks

Comment: @SnoringFrog : It is not recommended to do operations on find results unless they  null delimited(the `-print0` option). The approach mentioned in the other answer uses `-printf` which, I guess is a workaround. Also two `while` loops are totally unnecessary here.

Comment: @mona_sax : The double quotes around `"$old_dir/${arr[1]}` will take care word-splitting here, So I stand corrected in saying this won't process non-standard  file names. This script works as my test results confirm. Though I feel the second while loop is superfluous.

Comment: @mona_sax I used the second while loop only because I was having issues getting `-exec` to handle the command substitution properly. Those were the first two ways to come to mind to work on `find` results. Not sure what would be less superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Below script

```
while IFS=, read -ra arr # -r to prevent mangling backslashes
do
 find . -type f -name "${arr[0]}" -printf "mv '%p' '%h/${arr[1]}'" | bash
done<csvfile
```

should do it.

---

<sup>See [[ find ]](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) manpage to understand what the printf specifiers like %p,%h do</sup>

Comment: Hi sjjam, this hasn't worked, I'm getting an error for each file "mv: cannot stat `examplefillename.mov': No such file or directory". I don;t think this code is searching recursively, it only seems to be searching in the directory the script is in.

Comment: This does not even process the pairs from the `.csv` file properly. Adding an `echo` in front of the `mv` makes this readily apparent.

Comment: @bms9nmh : I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: @mona_sax:  The `%p` doesn't account for non-standard filenames but wrapping it in single quotes is a workaround for the issue you've pointed out for the other answer. Please see the edit.